# FFmpeg C++ APIs to detect if a video is rotated (shot on phone)

Tags: c++, video, ffmpeg

Using the FFmpeg C++ API, is there a way to determine if a video was shot on a phone and if its rotated?

When extracting the frames, the are rotated at a 90 degree angle, which is fine, but it would be good to report back that the video is rotated.

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/cmdutils.c#L2066) for clues.

Comment: If you post this as an answer, I'll except it, as it helped me solve the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ffmpeg autorotates videos if it detects a rotation tag.

[cmdutils.c](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/cmdutils.c#L2066) contains the function which checks for the rotation tag:

```
AVDictionaryEntry *rotate_tag = av_dict_get(st->metadata, "rotate", NULL, 0);
```

This should help.

Answer (score 0):

The width and height fields of an AVCodecContext for your video stream will let you determine the aspect ratio and thus if the video was shot portrait or landscape.

Comment: I've tried that.  The width and height for a video that is shot and played in portrait mode comes out as:  Width: 1920, Height: 1080

Comment: interesting, do you have a sample video? what does ffprobe say the SAR and DAR are?